# Need to integrate Unity output to TinCan API?

Tags: unity-game-engine, tin-can-api

I have developed a serious game(learning game) in Unity. I would like the game to be TinCan compliant. Can somebody tell me about the processes involved in making it TinCan compliant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tin Can compliancy doesn't really have a specific technical meaning, in so far as it can be tested objectively. Having said that, if your content tracks its experience (learning) data in a Learning Record Store (LRS), specifically a "conformant" LRS (see test suites or ask your vendor) then that content would generally be considered "Tin Can Compliant" because it is up to the LRS to enforce the requirements in the specification itself.

We (Rustici Software) have published a number of open source libraries that can be used to assist developers in communicating with an LRS in a conformant way, one or more of them can be used in a Unity application, and the list can be found at http://experienceapi.com/libraries/. There are several LRSs that are generally considered to be spec conformant, and our Cloud based product provides a free for testing LRS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Unity game example sending a xAPI statement

https://github.com/HT2-Labs/unity-xapi

It is sending one xAPI statement from `Start()` at game initialization.

To make this example work:

- git clone locally Unity example from github
- add it to your local Unity hub
- there will be warning about Unity old version of the example, select whatever Unity version you use and confirm version upgrade
- open `TinCanTest.cs` in Visual Studio, change

```
string endpoint = "https://ORG_NAME.learninglocker.net/data/xAPI";
string user = "KEY";
string password = "SECRET";
```

to credentials of your LRS and try running the game.

A similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382335/how-to-integrate-xapi-tincan-in-unity/).